# How to execute several animations sequentially with JQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to recreate an animation (some div sliding) N times, one right after the previous animation.

So far I've got this:

```
n_times = index;
for (var i = 0; i < n_times; i++) {
  $(".left").click();
}
```

and, that click event triggers:

```
$(".left").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    index--;
    column_n--;
    var total = parseInt($('#slides').css('margin-left').split('px')[0]) + 1150;
    $('#slides').stop().animate({ marginLeft: total + 'px' }, 850);
});
```

However, my first for loop does not wait for each animation to end to start the next call.

How can achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just make it recursive:

```
var times = 5; // or whatever you want
var total = parseInt($('#slides').css('margin-left').split('px')[0]) + 1150;

slide(0);

function slide(intv)
{
    if(intv <= times)
    {
        $('#slides').stop().animate({ marginLeft: total + 'px' }, 850, function(){
            intv += 1;
            slide(intv);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: touche, this is exactly what I was writing in as an answer before I saw yours. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in a for loop, but something like this:

```
function animateNTimes( n ) {
var isCanceled = false, i = 0;

    (function iteration(){

        if( isCanceled || i >= n ) {
        return;
        }

    i++;
    var total = parseInt($('#slides').css('margin-left').split('px')[0]) + 1150;
    $('#slides').animate({ marginLeft: total + 'px' }, 850, "swing", iteration );
    })();

    return {
        cancel: function(){
        $('#slides').stop()
        isCanceled = true;
        }
    };

}
```

You would then call it like this:

```
var myAnimation = animateNTimes( 5 );
```

and if you wanted to stop it while its going you could do

```
myAnimation.cancel();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3PNq/)